# React fontawesome

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I have static html file and used umd script like:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.8/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js" crossorigin></script>
```

I am trying to use font-awesome, how can I achieve it?

Comment: [Font Awesome now has an official React component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome), would it be a better option for you?

Comment: but is does not work with the script tags. May be I need font awesome CDN link something like: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/fortawesome/react-fontawesome.js

Comment: achieved using <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/js/all.min.js"></script>